# How do I add CSS to an element using jquery with only a class to identify the element and only if the time in innerHTML is within 5 minutes of now?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mediawiki

I have the following HTML:

```
<td class="mw-enhanced-rc">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;18:10&nbsp;</td>
```

I want to use JavaScript to make the time bold.

```
$('td[class^="mw-enhanced-rc"]').each(function() {
    this.style = this.style.fontWeight="bold";
}
```

↑ doesn't work, how can I fix it?

THEN, how do I make my page only apply the special formatting on times that are within a minute of the current time at page rendering?  My code as seen on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Technical_13/common.js:

```
/* Refresh my WatchList page when viewing every minute */
if (document.location.href == "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Watchlist") {
    setTimeout(function(){location = ''},60000);
    var timeNow = new Date();
    var minNow = timeNow.getMinutes();
    var minNow = minNow - 5;
    timeNow.setMinutes(minNow);
    var postTime = $('td.mw-enhanced-rc').html();
    for (i=0;i<6;i++) {var postTime = postTime.replace('&nbsp;', '');}
    var postTime = postTime.replace('<span class="mw-enhancedchanges-arrow-space"></span>', '');
    var postTime = postTime.replace('<abbr class="newpage" title="This edit created a new page">N</abbr>', '');
    var postTime = postTime.replace('<abbr class="minoredit" title="This is a minor edit">m</abbr>', '');
    var postTime = postTime.replace('<abbr class="botedit" title="This edit was performed by a bot">b</abbr>', '');
    var postTime = postTime.replace('<abbr class="unpatrolled" title="This edit has not yet been patrolled">!</abbr>', '');
    var postTime = postTime.split(':', '2');
    var postHour = postTime[0];
    var postMin = postTime[1];
    var timePost = new Date();
    timePost.setHours(postHour);
    timePost.setMinutes(postMin);
    if (timePost >= timeNow) {
        $('td.mw-enhanced-rc').css({
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '12pt'
        });
    }
}
```

↑ doesn't work, how can I fix it?
I've even tried adding:

```
var timePost = timePost.getTime();
var timeNow = timeNow.getTime();
```

just before the conditional if statement at the end it doesn't help.  Getting frustrated...

I also created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShoeMaker/z8vhp/3/) to work on it.

Edit: AH-HA!  Looks like my conditional statement IS working, but it is only evaluating the first instance on the page!  It then applies the `$('td.mw-enhanced-rc').css({fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '12pt'});` to ALL div elements instead of JUST the element that has the innerHTML that qualifies.  Can anyone help me refine this to only change the css (probably by injecting a style= attribute) of the div elements that qualify?

Comment: You have a syntax error, remove the first `this.style =`

Comment: You're missing a closing `);` at the end of the function too.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I'm using this on a MediaWiki site that parses my JavaScript and throws errors if the last declaration on the page has a closing ;  -- I have no idea why it does this, but that is why I left it off.

Comment: Okay, I'm playing with the second part of my problem in JSfiddle, and it seems that I am not getting the innerHTML of my div. `var PostTime = document.div.mw-enhanced-rc.innerHTML;` is not giving me the contents?

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify it by doing:

```
$('td.mw-enhanced-rc').css({fontWeight: 'bold'});
```

Comment: How about the second part of the question to make it only work if time is within 1 minute of current time?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because of your expression:

`this.style = this.style.fontWeight="bold";`

this expression must be like that:

`this.style.fontWeight = "bold";`

You are already using jQuery (or Zepto), so you can use the css() method

```
$('td[class^="mw-enhanced-rc"]').each(function() {
    $(this).css('fontWeight', 'bold');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$('td.mw-enhanced-rc').each(function()
   {
      this.style.fontWeight = "bold";
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution code that answered ALL parts of the question and worked to accomplish what I was looking for was:

```
var timeNow = new Date();
var minNow = timeNow.getMinutes();
var minNow = minNow - 5;
timeNow.setMinutes(minNow);
var postTime = $('td.mw-enhanced-rc').html();
for (i=0;i<6;i++) {var postTime = postTime.replace('&nbsp;', '');}
var postTime = postTime.replace('<span class="mw-enhancedchanges-arrow-space"></span>', '');
var postTime = postTime.replace('<abbr class="newpage" title="This edit created a new page">N</abbr>', '');
var postTime = postTime.replace('<abbr class="minoredit" title="This is a minor edit">m</abbr>', '');
var postTime = postTime.replace('<abbr class="botedit" title="This edit was performed by a bot">b</abbr>', '');
var postTime = postTime.replace('<abbr class="unpatrolled" title="This edit has not yet been patrolled">!</abbr>', '');
var postTime = postTime.split(':', '2');
var postHour = postTime[0];
var postMin = postTime[1];
var timePost = new Date();
timePost.setHours(postHour);
timePost.setMinutes(postMin);
var timePost = timePost.getTime();
var timeNow = timeNow.getTime();
if (timePost >= timeNow) {
    var enhRC = $('td.mw-enhanced-rc').html();
    $('td[class^="mw-enhanced-rc"]').each(function() {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(enhRC, '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">' + enhRC + '</span>');
    });
}
```